# Whats does the green shade of packages mean in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svn, android-debug

I just imported a project from subversion to Android studio, The projects run fine.One  thing i noticed is the packages list under the **project files have a green shade background whats that means**, I am facing difficulties while debugging the project, **while debugging the control goes to correct line but the values are not available** to view, is that any thing related to that green shade, if yes **do there is any way to remove that**?

[image]

Comment: I believe the shade has nothing to do with debugging. It's just an ide way to highlight packages.

Comment: @Muhammad Thank you Muhammad for your response, No the green shade isn't highlighting of packages.I am not certain about the indication but it have some meaning for instance "generated "or something like that..

Comment: Actually the green shade represent the directories for test(unit test) and androidTest.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for that info, can i found some doc on that some where, and some way to remove the directories from test(unit test) to make them run as normal

Comment: These packages are only for test and won't run until you run a test on your module. It's safe to delete them. Where is your main directory? Did you properly downloaded and imported the project?

Comment: ok, may be there is a problem in project structure itself, i have only a subversion link.So the real problem may lies in the project in svn. Will check that..Thanks for the great effort